# How to know if a GRPC server is available

Tags: python, linux, grpc

If a gRPC client starts before the server, it exits with an exception. The application I am working on starts a bunch of servers and clients (near) simultaneously, however, and I have to be robust with respect to execution order. If the client starts before the server, I want it to wait until the server shows up.

I modified the HelloWorld python client example as follows:

```
done = False
while not done:
    try:
        response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'), timeout=1)
        print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)
        done = True
    except:
        print('Waiting for server connect...')
        time.sleep(1)
```

so now if I start the client before the server, I get the 'Waiting for server connect...' message scrolling up my terminal window as expected. Then I start the server, and it connects... eventually. In fact it takes about ten seconds before the 'Hello you' messages appears, which is surprisingly long. Why might it be so slow, and is there a robust way to check for server connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [ChannelConnectivity](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.ChannelConnectivity) - I am a go programmer but it should be the same in python. What I do is create while/for loop and when the "ChannelConnectivity" is set to "READY" I create the client from the connection and then continue.

Comment: Note that "WaitForReady" RPCs should generally be preferred to observing the connectivity state manually. I've not found that API in Python though.

Comment: [Wait for ready](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/wait-for-ready/) semantics are now available for Python via the `wait_for_ready` flag ([example from grpc source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/wait_for_ready)).

This was introduced in 2018, [version 1.17.0](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.17.0), and graduated from "experimental" state in 2023 with [version 1.53.0](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.53.0)

Answer (score 9):

```
import grpc

TIMEOUT_SEC = 15
def grpc_server_on(channel) -> bool:
    try:
        grpc.channel_ready_future(channel).result(timeout=TIMEOUT_SEC)
        return True
    except grpc.FutureTimeoutError:
        return False
```

The `channel_ready_future` function allows the client to wait for a specified timeout duration (in seconds) for the server to be ready. If our client times out, it raises.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [Wait-for-Ready](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/wait-for-ready/) semantics.

As of 2018, this is built-in for Python via the `wait_for_ready` flag. The grpc GitHub source has a few examples: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/wait_for_ready

Translating your question directly, you'd want something like this:

```py
response = stub.SayHello(
    helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'), 
    timeout=1,
    wait_for_ready=True
)
print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)
```

`wait_for_ready` was introduced for Python in 2018, [version 1.17.0](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.17.0), and graduated from "experimental" state in 2023 with [version 1.53.0](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.53.0)