# Check grpc server availability?

Tags: grpc

Is there any way to check that `grpc-server` is up without making actual procedure calls and implementing additional queries (i.e. `rpc HealthCheck (Input) returns (Status)`)?

Comment: You can probably use a HEAD request (https://ochronus.com/http-head-request-good-uses/), but I don't know the supported grpc call for that

Comment: Wouldn't the same *failure*, as part of the normal call, serves as that purpose? I don't see any difference...just more code on your side: the fault-tolerance and what not routine(s) to check for failures; if successfully, the fault-tolerance and what not, again, routine(s) for the "normal" call. Anything can happens between a successful call and the next one...even if they are separated by milliseconds. You need to account for that. All the time.

Comment: Here is a python solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61384353/7127824

Answer (score 6):

Most clients should use the [channel state API](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/connectivity-semantics-and-api.md#channel-state-api). In Java, for instance, that is available via `state = managedChannel.getState(false);`. Treating {IDLE, CONNECTING, READY} as "good" is appropriate in many circumstances, but if you are very latency sensitive you can only consider READY as "good" and should pass `true` to `getState()`.

Note that the API does not actively monitor the service's health; it just informs whether the server is currently known to be running and reachable. If you need to know about the service's precise health, then you need to use the Health service, via RPCs. But this is generally expected to be rare, except by load balancers (and not by clients using load balancers).

Comment: I was having a look into Java client, and it seems both `getState` and `notifyWhenStateChanged` are experimental APIs yet :-(

Comment: I am new to gRPC. So was wondering, when you mentioned "Most clients should use the channel state API.", is it more like a specification that all client implementations "have" to follow or is it more of a recommendation ?

Comment: It's "if your application needs to monitor dependency health (e.g., to report its own health), generally using the channel state API is the most appropriate approach." Rarely should you use the API to make behavior decisions, as generally you should just let the RPC fail instead (it is less app code and provides informative error message). Channel state API is great for informing others whether the service is healthy (e.g., for a LB system to avoid your backend, or to expose a "trouble connecting" icon in an Android app").