# Methods of checking status of grpc server in python

Tags: python, grpc

I have a grpc server running at on of my machine. Is there any way to continuously check if that server is running or not other than making a query to the server?

Like in c++ it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/connectivity-semantics-and-api.md#channel-state-api) that using

```
grpc_connectivity_state GetState(bool try_to_connect);
```

will give connectivity status. Do we have any option similar to this in python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231339/check-grpc-server-availability

Comment: Thanks @piertoni, I've already checked that answer but in the documentation of python grpc [here](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html) I didn't find any equivalent method.

Answer (score 0):

The method `grpc_connectivity_state GetState(bool try_to_connect)` will try to create connect if `try_to_connect` is true when disconnected, and it's basic API for channel, python had it also, you can reference [grpc.aio.Channel.get_state](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html?highlight=state#grpc.aio.Channel.get_state);

And this method is for connect, not for server, maybe you need [health check](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_health_checking.html) to check if server can work correcttly more than check connect status.

Comment: what if I don't use grpc.aio api?

Comment: find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61384353/6088796

Comment: That doesn't help @Jackiexiao . When I delete the file for unix connection it still returns true